# Issue Running Cells in Jupyter Notebook on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run cells inside Jupyter Notebook, but it keeps on giving me this strange error. I am not sure if it is related to VS Code update or something else:

Failed to connect to remote Jupyter notebook. Check that the Jupyter Server URI setting has a valid running server specified. http://localhost:8888/ TypeError: request to http://localhost:8888/api/contents/?1589373068313 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Pratik G I'm a developer on this extension. When you select the "Python: Specify local or remote jupyter server for connection" command what is that set to?